# Как реализовать данный блок?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как реализовать данный выделенный блок? Пробовал дивом но надо еще и одновременный hover с цифрой и нижним border реализовать:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 1020px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.block {
  width: 980px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid gray;
}

block::after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 6%;
  background-color: gray;
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 78%;
}

.block p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.list {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
}

.promo {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-right: 140px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <p class="list">1</p>
    <p class="promo">Simple</p>
    <p class="list">2</p>
    <p class="promo">Transparent</p>
    <p class="list">3</p>
    <p class="promo">Collaborative</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQbgXR)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста код с вашими попытками.

Comment: Похоже на табы, head tabs - ol > li

Answer (score 1):

Не лучшая моя реализация, но имея под рукой только псевдо-картинку и не имея описание от автора, что именно он хочет, могу только так...
Цвета уважаемый автор добавлены для того, что бы ты имел представление, что где да как....

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 1020px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.block {
  border-bottom: 4px solid gray;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.list {
  margin-left: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: gray;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
}

.promo {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-right: 140px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.block1 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.block2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.block3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.block:hover {
  background-color: cyan;
  border-bottom: 4px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block block1">
    <p class="list">1</p>
    <p class="promo">Simple</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block block2">
    <p class="list">2</p>
    <p class="promo">Transparent</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block block3">
    <p class="list">3</p>
    <p class="promo">Collaborative</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Покойся с миром, семантика.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, о чем ты?))))

Comment: Я о том, что несмотря на обилие тегов, подходящих очень хорошо для разметки этого блока, ты пользуешься только дивами и параграфами )

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, когда я был новичком и задавал вопрос, то мне было зачастую не понятно,  когда меня не то что надо было... Ты прав, я там много чего бы изменил...  Но это всего то пример... На мой взгляд  , лучше показать, то что хотел человек на своем примере.... Тем более, поверь, если бы он хотя бы участвовал в обсуждении, я бы  по другому оформил ответ, и много чего хорошего ему посоветовал....

Comment: я хотел сделать блок с нижним border и чтоб при наведении  hover выделялось зеленым циферка и отдельный пункт,я начал уже предполагать что это список

Comment: @verstak44444, Когда задаешь вопрос, желательно описать его. Тут все откликнуться, чтобы  помочь. Когда я писал тебе ответ, я не увидел  информации ни о бордере ни о ховере ни о круглом значке....  это потом оказалось в описании в пару строк...  Если тебе какой то ответ подошел  и удовлетворил твоим требованиям прими этот  ответ. Серая галочка слева от ответа.   Это будет  словом  `спасибо` за помощь...  В будущем старайся выкладывать код и подробно объяснять что ты хотел, что не получилось и какой должен быть конечный результат....  Ответ получишь на много быстрее и более грамотны...  Удачи

Comment: @Air просто имей в виду, что люди очень часто копируют сниппеты кода, которые находят на стеке. Это, конечно, на их совести, но не лишним будет понимать, что ты оказываешь влияние более, чем на одного человека, которому пишешь ответ.

Comment: Если человек копирует код не понимая, это говорит о его проф пригодности...  Если даже он скопирует мой идеальный код.... И чей то еще не менее  грамотный, это не значит, что его верстка будет идеальной....Это сугубо мое личное мнение....

Answer (score 1):

Как то так

```css
.counter{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  counter-reset: myCounter;
  display:inline-flex;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}
.counter li{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  top:1px;
  padding:10px 0;
  margin-right:40px;
  border-bottom:inherit;
}
.counter li:last-child{
  margin-right:0;
}
.counter li:before{
  content:counter(myCounter);
  counter-increment: myCounter;
  display:inline-block;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:20px;
  background-color:#ddd;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin-right:10px;
}
.counter li:hover,
.counter li.active{
  border-color:green;
}
.counter li:hover:before,
.counter li.active:before{
  background-color:green
}
```

```html
<ol class="counter">
  <li>simple</li>
  <li>transparent</li>
  <li>collaborative</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: вот именно так хотел,но еще бы чтоб линия по ширине блока совпадала

Comment: Внес правки. Это имелось в виду?

Comment: да,а как называются подобные блоки?

Comment: если эти блоки переключают видимость какого-нибудь контента на странице, то это называется "табы".

Comment: ну вот видимо это при hover просто не знал как называется

Comment: но суть в том что это просто как список как видится мне идет на макете с border-bottom и hover

Comment: Ничего не понял.

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tabs {
  padding: 25px;
}

.tabs__head {
  counter-reset: item;
  font-size: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}

.tabs__head>li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 33.3333%;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

.tabs__head>li:before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counter(item) " ";
  background: #222;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 7px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.tabs__head>li>a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #222;
  padding: 15px;
}

.tabs__head>li:hover:before,
.tabs__head>li:hover>a {
  opacity: .7;
}

.tabs__head>li.active {
  border-color: green;
}

.tabs__head>li.active:before {
  background: green;
  opacity: 1;
}

.tabs__head>li.active>a {
  color: green;
  opacity: 1;
}

.tabs__content {
  display: none;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.tabs__content:first-of-type {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <ol class="tabs__head">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="tabs__contents">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tabs__content">
      Content Tab 1
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tabs__content">
      Content Tab 2
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tabs__content">
      Content Tab 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```